# Which creational pattern best describes this code?

Tags: c++, object, design-patterns, factory

I am studying design patterns (no, this is not for school, but my own edification and self-improvement). A project that I have worked on has the following architecture for one of its components:

```
class ProductFactory {
    static AbstractProduct * getProduct() {
        #ifdef ANDROID
            return new AndroidProduct;
        #elif defined IOS
            return new IOSProduct;
        #endif
            return 0;
    }
};
```

I'm having a terrible time trying to classify this code according to my readings on Abstract Factory and Factory Method. For example, the creator class is concrete and only one kind of product is created (as opposed to the canonical window, scrollbar, etc.). But which product-by-platform is created is not deferred to sub-classes -- rather, different sub-classes are created by the one creator class.

So my question is very simple: what pattern does the above code most/best conform to, and why?

Much appreciated!

Comment: I believe this is generally referred to as `#ifdef hell`

Comment: This is attempt at an Abstract Factory pattern by someone who hasn't a clue, it seems to me. If it's a project you've worked on, why not ask the author of that code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what pattern does the above code most/best conform to, and why?

This is not an actual pattern per-se; however, a concrete class whose only purpose is to instantiate the right implementation is more commonly known as a *Simple Factory*.

This *idiom* is useful when the concrete implementations that you want to instantiate are limited to a handful of permutation-combinations.

Answer (score -1):

I would say this is a

Broker-Pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broker_Pattern

Proxy-Pattern https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern

inside a Abstract factory pattern

Comment: I don't believe the code demonstrated by the OP is either the broker or the proxy pattern.